# How to copy the tooltip content in a GWT application?

Tags: html, gwt, tooltip

I am using HTML setTitle (http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#setTitle(java.lang.String)) to set the tooltip content for a cell.

Is there a way for users to copy the tooltip content ?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, once a user moves a cursor, the tooltip disappears. So it's impossible to copy its content.

You can implement your own tooltip by showing a small PopupPanel on MouseOver event, but you will have the same problem if you want to automatically hide this panel on MouseOut.

Your best option may be to use a context menu (right click) to offer an option to copy the cell's content.